# Undefined is not an object when setting item in AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

In my React Native app, I want to store the token into `AsyncStorage` but when trying to do so, it throws the following warning.I went through many SO answers regarding this kind of issues but couldn't come up with a solution.

[image]

**SignupScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import PhoneInput from "react-native-phone-input";
import {
  Button,
  Text,
  Form,
  Item as FormItem,
  Input,
  Label,
} from 'native-base';

export default class Signup extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: "Signup",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fname: "",
      mobile: "",
    };

  }

  setToken = async () => {
    //This is where the warning is throws
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', 'tokka').then(
      val => {
        if(val) this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop: "40%"}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign: "center",fontSize: 40}}>OnTask</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20,textAlign: "center"}}>Signup</Text>
        <Form>
        <FormItem>
          <Label>First Name</Label>
          <Input />
        </FormItem>

        <Label style={{marginTop: "3%",marginLeft: "4%"}}>Mobile Number</Label>
          <PhoneInput
          ref="phone"
          style={{
            height: 50,
            padding: 10,            
            width: 300,
            marginLeft: "2%",
            marginBottom: "5%",
            borderRadius: 10
          }}
          onChangePhoneNumber={ number => this.setState({mobile: number})}
/>

        <Button full primary onPress={() => this.setToken()}>
          <Text> Sign Up </Text>
        </Button>

      </Form>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this you're importing AsyncStorage wrong. please import AsyncStorage without curly braces.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

instead of

```
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

And for the best practice use the try and catch

```
setToken = async () => {
  try {
    const val = await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', 'tokka');
    if(val) this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e.message);
  }
}
```